# ELF relocate against local section

Tags: linker, elf, ld

I'm trying to create my own ELF .o files in which I want to write out strips of memory that point at other strips of memory. I don't want to give every strip a name, so I just keep track of their position relative to the start of the section they are in.

So I create a relocation-entry in the form of:

`000000000a50  00090000000b R_X86_64_32S      0000000000000000 .section + a70`

where at a50 we refer to an object at .section + a70, using a 64bit global pointer. The section is defined using:

`9: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL   DEFAULT    6`

The previous output is from readelf and it actually pretends that everything is fine ... until I pull this through LD, which just segfaults.

I found out that if I use a WEAK type that it sorta works... but it seems like it uses the first section symbol it finds in all linked .o files as the target for ALL relocations in that case. I really want it to be local, so LOCAL it should be.

The alternative I have until now is just creating an OBJECT symbol at the beginning of each section that has such objects, but that just seems silly... Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in LD?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had an off-by-1 in the `sh_info` field of the symbol table. I figured it out with the help of GOLD, which is a bit more informative by not just segfaulting but also giving:

```
    gold: internal error in do_layout, at ../../gold/object.cc:1493
```

or

```
    gold: error: invalid STB_LOCAL symbol in external symbols
    gold: error: unsupported symbol binding 0
    gold: error: invalid STB_LOCAL symbol in external symbols
    gold: error: unsupported symbol binding 0
    gold: error: test.o: multiple definition of ''
    gold: test.o: previous definition here
```

This helped me identify that my local symbols ended up in the "external symbols" (meaning after the "index of the first non-local symbol", stored in `sh_info`)